# Print booklet like in Adobe InDesign for PDF files?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, print-design, adobe-acrobat

I use the print booklet feature in Adobe InDesign to print little booklets.  I actually then slice the booklet down the middle to have convenient half-size pages printed front and backside.  Works great.

Problem now is we've segmented or documents to make an InDesign book and it no longer gives us the option to print booklets.

How can I print booklets like that with just a PDF file.  I was really surprised Adobe Acrobat not only didn't have a print booklet feature, but it also doesn't have any mechanism whatsoever to print front and back of pages with 2-up!

There must be a PDF reader that can do this or extension to acrobat, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your document exports to PDF as individual pages (i.e., not as spreads), then it's easy to do in Acrobat. The booklet printing functionality in InDesign didn't make it past CS3.

- Select Print
- In the dialog, under "Paper Sizing and Handling" choose "Booklet"
- Select which subset of pages to print: Both Sides, Front Side Only or Back Side Only.

Comment: Didn't think to check in Paper Sizing!  Trying it now, thanks.

Comment: But how can I save it to a new pdf? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/45680/36884